# Scientific Linux 6.4 not working after restart

Tags: linux, scientific-linux

I have Windows and Scientific Linux 6.4 as well. One day I switched on my computer and I selected Scientific Linux (SL) in Grub (Windows is preselected). When I was in SL, I was not getting the Wi-Fi on light (which was there in Windows, when I shut it down). So I restarted SL, but after that I saw a blank screen.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, it restarts again, and if I enter something, it shows

```
status{DRY ERR}
error{UNC}
```

Help me in this matter. I am not able to open my SL 6.4, and I consider this to be a critical issue.

Comment: Is `status{DRY ERR}` or `status{DRDY ERR}` ?

Comment: @Cornelius, first one

Comment: @Cornelius, Can help me in this matter.

Comment: Generally these types of errors indicate hard drive failure, but it might just be corruption. Either way unlikely to boot fully again.

Comment: @ssmy, How to go about this.

Comment: @lavkush judging from what you have said, you need to restore from backups. Might be able to save some data by plugging the drive into another system. Can't know more from that data.

Comment: I suggest to first boot from a live CD and save your data to an external disk, because you might need to reinstall Linux (and in that case, do not go this time for dual-boot).

Comment: @harrymc, live CD should be of linux. Then what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the boot CD of [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage).
You can find on the SystemRescueCd website documentation in the form of both a Quick start and a Manual.

Use SystemRescueCd to boot and copy your files to an external disk, verify that you have everything saved in at least two copies, before wiping out your disk and restarting from scratch and installing anew Scientific Linux
(and in that case, do not go this time for dual-boot).

You may alternatively use a boot CD of Ubuntu or whatever other flavor of Linux that
you feel comfortable with.

If you can take out your hard disk and use it in another computer, you could backup
your files without a boot CD.

Sorry for this brutal method, but I don't think that it's possible for me or
somebody else here to fix your disk without hands-on on your computer.
If I tried doing remote-control of your efforts through this forum,
I could do more harm than good.

I also cannot go to more details than that, because tutorials are not allowed by the rules of this forum, and probably the available documentation may be better than anything I could do.
If you don't feel comfortable with this, don't take chances with your data
and get help from a more experienced person.

Next time, ensure that you always have external backups of your data.

Comment: Is this is not possible without restarting it from scratch. I will try this but by only a restart, don't know how SL 6.4 got corrupted.

Comment: I was not able to use Systemrescue CD, may be because of ignorance. Thanks for the help.

Comment: SL also has a live CD.

Comment: I tried it, by using x86_64, after that also my SL is not opening, same blank screen. So, finally I installed Ubuntu 14.04.